# Spring MVC Default or no-arg constructor in configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

   private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  public ApplicationConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @Bean(name="clientRepository")
  ClientRepository jpaClientRepository() {
    return new JpaClientRepository();
   }
}
```

I just found a Core Spring  4.2 Certification Mock  Exam and regarding this class it says that `"Default or no-arg constructor is mandatory."`
I tried this class in a test I made and it works perfectly without Default or   no-arg constructor (?) , SO I think there is no need of a Default or    no-arg constructor

Comment: It depends... Up until Spring 4.2 it was, after that 4.3 and later it isn't anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Spring version is <= 4.2 then that statement is true. However for Spring >= 4.3 it is allowed to have a `@Configuration` class without a no-args constructor.

See also the [Core Container Improvements](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_core_container_improvements_3) section in the reference guide about this. It has been implemented with issue [SPR-13471](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13471) in Spring 4.3 RC1.

**Pro Tip:** if you only have a single constructor you don't need `@Autowired` on the constructor anymore. (See [SPR-12278](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13471)) for that).